# Error while adding platform to Cordova App in Eclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

After creating a new Cordova project in Eclipse (Mars) when I click Finish, it starts adding platform to my app but ends up throwing the following error and the platform is not added:

```
X:\CordovaWorkspace\DemoProject>cordova prepare Discovered platform
"android@5.3.0-nightly.2016.7.6.103e1e8d" in config.xml. Adding it to
the project Adding android project... Running command: cmd "/s /c
"C:\Users\XYZ\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\5.3.0-nightly.2016.7.6.103e1e8d\bin\create.bat

X:\CordovaWorkspace\DemoProject\platforms\android demo.project "Demo
Project" --cli"" module.js:327
    throw err;
     ^

 Error: Cannot find module 'sax'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
      at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
      at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XYZ\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\5.3.0-nightly.2016.7.6.103e1e8d\node_modules\elementtree\lib\parsers\sax.js:3:11)
      at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
 at Module.require (module.js:353:17) Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error: No platforms added to this project. Please use
 `cordova platform add <platform>`.

 X:\CordovaWorkspace\DemoProject>exit
```

[image]

How can it be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to manually resolve the sax requirement by downloading the sax module and placing it in a folder called sax.

or use `npm install` 
in case you don't find the sax mmodule in the internet you can create sax.js in your node-elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js and put this code below:

```
var util = require('util');

var sax = require('sax');

var TreeBuilder = require('./../treebuilder').TreeBuilder;

function XMLParser(target) {
  this.parser = sax.parser(true);

  this.target = (target) ? target : new TreeBuilder();

  this.parser.onopentag = this._handleOpenTag.bind(this);
  this.parser.ontext = this._handleText.bind(this);
  this.parser.oncdata = this._handleCdata.bind(this);
  this.parser.ondoctype = this._handleDoctype.bind(this);
  this.parser.oncomment = this._handleComment.bind(this);
  this.parser.onclosetag = this._handleCloseTag.bind(this);
  this.parser.onerror = this._handleError.bind(this);
}

XMLParser.prototype._handleOpenTag = function(tag) {
  this.target.start(tag.name, tag.attributes);
};

XMLParser.prototype._handleText = function(text) {
  this.target.data(text);
};

XMLParser.prototype._handleCdata = function(text) {
  this.target.data(text);
};

XMLParser.prototype._handleDoctype = function(text) {
};

XMLParser.prototype._handleComment = function(comment) {
};

XMLParser.prototype._handleCloseTag = function(tag) {
  this.target.end(tag);
};

XMLParser.prototype._handleError = function(err) {
  throw err;
};

XMLParser.prototype.feed = function(chunk) {
  this.parser.write(chunk);
};

XMLParser.prototype.close = function() {
  this.parser.close();
  return this.target.close();
};

exports.XMLParser = XMLParser;
```